# Razor table deleted row keeping ID

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using Razor to display a list of model, and the end user can add or remove entries to that list.  After clicking a "Remove" button, the view model is kicked back into the Controller Post to remove the list entry and returned to the View via `return View(model);`.  The hidden IDs of each entry, though, seem to have just had the last row deleted and the other displayed rows moved up by one, resulting in data repopulated to an incorrect ID if another item is added to the list.

The Controller is generating the correct data, which has been verified by checking the parameters on the `return View(model);`, so the issue is that the HTML table "saves" some values instead of wiping it and recreating it after each return to the View.

In other words, if the first RecipientUserID is 14 and the second is 20, deleting the row of 14 first leaves the displayed data for 20, but the View source says the RecipientUserID is 14, and adding another item changes the first row from 20's data to 14 and that data.  Is there a way to reload the table and have the hidden field on the same row with its associated other data?  Thanks in advance!

View Model:

```
public class NewMailModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public List<RecipientModel> Recipients { get; set; }

    public int CorporateID { get; set; }

    public string AddedName { get; set; }
}
```

RecipientModel:

```
public class RecipientModel
{
    public int RecipientUserID { get; set; }

    public string RecipientName { get; set; }

    public string RecipientEmail { get; set; }

    public bool RemoveRecipient { get; set; }
}
```

Pertinent Razor:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="cTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="display:none"></th>
                    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">E-mail</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Select</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.Recipients.Any())
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Recipients.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td style="display:none">@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipients[i].RecipientUserID)</td>
                            <td align="center">@Model.Recipients[i].RecipientName</td>
                            <td align="center">@Model.Recipients[i].RecipientEmail</td>
                            <td align="center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Recipients[i].RemoveRecipient)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <button type="submit" id="removeRecipient" class="btn btn-info removeRecipient pull-right" value="Remove Recipient" name="buttonCommand">Remove Selected</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">

     </div>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewMail(NewMailModel model, string buttonCommand)
{
    if (buttonCommand == "Send")
    {
        //Miscellaneous code
    }
    else if (buttonCommand == "Add")
    {
        //After a removal and subsequent adding, the removed 
        //     RecipientUserID is used here because it was never 
        //     evacuated from the Razor table!!!
        RecipientModel added = GetFullRecipient(model.AddedName);
        int recipientIndex = -1;
        if (model.Recipients != null)
        {
            recipientIndex = model.Recipients.FindIndex(m => m.RecipientUserID == added.RecipientUserID);
            model.Recipients = GetMissingData(model.CorporateID, model.Recipients);
        }
        else
        {
            model.Recipients = new List<RecipientModel>();
        }
        if (recipientIndex == -1)
        {
            model.Recipients.Add(added);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Remove from list works, but the removed RecipientUserID 
        //     is still hidden in the Razor table and is assigned 
        //     to the next row that moves up into the deleted row's space!!!
        if (model.Recipients != null && model.Recipients.Count > 0)
        {
            List<RecipientModel> newRecipients = new List<RecipientModel>();
            foreach (var entry in model.Recipients)
            {
                if (entry.RemoveRecipient == false)
                {
                    RecipientModel mailTo = new RecipientModel
                    {
                        RecipientEmail = entry.RecipientEmail,
                        RecipientName = entry.RecipientName,
                        RecipientUserID = entry.RecipientUserID,
                        RemoveRecipient = false
                    };
                    newRecipients.Add(mailTo);
                }
            }
            model.Recipients = new List<RecipientModel>();
            model.Recipients = newRecipient;
            model.Recipients = GetMissingData(model.CorporateID, model.Recipients);
        }
        else
        {
            model.Recipients = new List<RecipientModel>();
        }
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public List<RecipientModel> GetMissingData(int CorporateID, List<RecipientModel> Recipients)
    {
        DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
        var people = db.uspGetUsers(CorporateID).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < Recipients.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < people.Count; x++)
            {
                if (Recipients[i].RecipientUserID == people[x].UserID)
                {
                    Recipients[i].RecipientEmail = people[x].UserEmail;
                    Recipients[i].RecipientName = people[x].UserLastName + ", " + people[x].UserFirstName;
                    Recipients[i].RemoveRecipient = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return Recipients;
    }
```

HTML Source With 2 Table Rows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RecipientUserID must be a number." data-val-required="The RecipientUserID field is required." id="Recipients_0__RecipientUserID" name="Recipients[0].RecipientUserID" type="hidden" value="14" /></td>
        <td align="center">Simpson, Lisa</td>
        <td align="center">email@gmail.com</td>
        <td align="center"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The RemoveRecipient field is required." id="Recipients_0__RemoveRecipient" name="Recipients[0].RemoveRecipient" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Recipients[0].RemoveRecipient" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RecipientUserID must be a number." data-val-required="The RecipientUserID field is required." id="Recipients_1__RecipientUserID" name="Recipients[1].RecipientUserID" type="hidden" value="25" /></td>
        <td align="center">Scorpio, Hank</td>
        <td align="center">email@gmail.com</td>
        <td align="center"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The RemoveRecipient field is required." id="Recipients_1__RemoveRecipient" name="Recipients[1].RemoveRecipient" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Recipients[1].RemoveRecipient" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

HTML Source with 1 Table Row after Deleting First Row (note the RecipientUserID is the value of the deleted row (14), not of the row/data being displayed (25)!):

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RecipientUserID must be a number." data-val-required="The RecipientUserID field is required." id="Recipients_0__RecipientUserID" name="Recipients[0].RecipientUserID" type="hidden" value="14" /></td>
        <td align="center">Scorpio, Hank</td>
        <td align="center">email@gmail.com</td>
        <td align="center"><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The RemoveRecipient field is required." id="Recipients_0__RemoveRecipient" name="Recipients[0].RemoveRecipient" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Recipients[0].RemoveRecipient" type="hidden" value="false" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Since we can't see how you populate your model or handle the removal process it's quite hard to see what might be going wrong. It's doesn't appear to be an issue in the HTML or view code as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! When checking the values on the 'return View(model)', all of the values of the model list are accurate. I'll post an edit with the Controller code, but it looks like the View is just cutting off the last row and only populating the parameters that aren't hidden.

Comment: `model.Recipients = new List<RecipientModel>();
            model.Recipients = newRecipient;
            model.Recipients = GetMissingData(CorporateID, model.Recipients);` . In these three lines you repeatedly re-assign the "recipients" property of the model to different values. The first line is simply redundant - there's no point in creating an empty list and then immediately replacing it with a different, already-created list. It's just a waste of time. Also I assume `model.Recipients = newRecipient;` is a typo and should be `newRecipients;` at the end (there's an "s" missing)?

Comment: The second and third lines here might be the problem. On the second line you assign the model property to be the list of recipients minus the ones you removed. But then after that you immediately re-assign the property to be whatever the result of the "GetMissingData()" method is (and I can't see that method, so I have no idea what it will return). This will over-write what you assigned on the previous line. So again the 2nd line is redundant, just write `model.Recipients = GetMissingData(CorporateID, newRecipients);` and remove the other two

Comment: So that streamlines the code a bit, but since the new list of recipients to be passed into your view comes from the result of GetMissingData(), I still can't tell you what's wrong without seeing that method.

Comment: @ADyson - Any of the table data that is not hidden or the CheckBoxFor will not be returned/are returned as "null" to the Controller, so the seemingly redundant calls are actually repopulating that display data.  When checking the values on the 'return View(model);' line, all of the Controller code is correctly retrieving data, it's just that the HTML table doesn't repopulate after returning to the View each time.  I'll check around more to see if there's a way to do that.

Comment: "the seemingly redundant calls are actually repopulating that display data"...except that they aren't because you immediately overwrite the same variable's value with something else. That was my whole point. It's a basic principle of variable assignment in C# (and most other languages). So that data never gets returned to the view (note "View", not controller - you're in the Controller now, the View is where you send the model data back to, for displaying).

Comment: To expand on the point, if I write `string a = "abc"; string b = "xyz"; a = b; Console.WriteLine(a);` then will the output be "abc" or "xyz"? Clearly it will be "xyz" because you replaces the earlier value of `a` with the value from `b`. Same with your code - `model.Recipients = newRecipients;` assigns the filtered values (without all the removed data) to `model.Recipients`. But on the next line you replace the value in `model.Recipients` with a different value - it becomes whatever value is coming from the GetMissingData() method instead.

Comment: If you are seeing "null" values in the Recipient data which comes back to the View, then presumably that must be generated by the GetMissingData() method. So if you want that debugging, then please show it. If you believe what it outputs is correct, then please show a sample of before/after model data, because perhaps I am missing the point about what is different in the data. But the Razor code in the View literally just displays what it's given, it doesn't try to change the data, so it's hard to see how that could be causing the incorrect output.

Comment: N.B. _"the HTML table "saves" some values instead of wiping it and recreating it after each return to the View."_ ...this is literally impossible in a web application. When you post back to the server, the previous version of the page ceases to exist. The browser discards it, and replaces it with whatever HTML it gets from the server. Nothing is preserved, nothing is merged, it's just replaced completely with no messing. In your case, that new HTML will be whatever HTML is generated by the Razor code, based on the updated model data it receives from the controller action which was fired

Comment: @ADyson - The GetMissingData() method fills in the RecipientName and RecipientEmail values because those are returned as null to the Controller.  It wasn't as clear as it could've been, but the idea behind creating a new List<Model> and assigning it to the View Model was to take the original values that should be displayed and get them anew in case the View Model's list was somehow retaining the wrong ID.  Regardless, the Controller is getting the data it's instructed to get, and the HTML table appears to be retaining the deleted UserID.

Comment: you'll have to show a before/after example of the model data then so we can actually run it. Because what you're saying doesn't appear to add up to what the code you've shown would do. And for completeness please still show GetMissingData() as well in case there's some non-obvious logical error in there which is causing a problem, even though it sounds like it has a different purpose. It's always easier to debug a complete code sequence than one with missing bits. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll await the sample model data as well, then take a closer look

Comment: @ADyson - The HTML source has been added, which should also include the model data.  The Controller seems to be handling the information correctly, but the ID of 14 after a deletion is not the ID of the remaining row, so the data corresponding to ID 14 is technically "correct", but not the data of what should've been the remaining row ID.  Does that make sense?  Thanks again!

Comment: @jle Please read the text of the `model-view-controller` tag: "For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [asp.net-mvc] or [asp.net-core-mvc] tag instead.".  Removing this tag, as your question is not about the pattern, and is indeed about `asp.net-mvc`.

Comment: Ok it _is_ the view code after all, sorry. But I needed the data to be able to run it and be sure. It's something to do with the Html.HiddenFor. If you replace it with a manually generated hidden field then it works fine: `<td style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="Recipients[@i].RecipientUserID" value="@Model.Recipients[i].RecipientUserID" /></td>` . Only problem is I don't really know _why_. Not sure if it's a bug, or a misunderstanding of how to use it. I'd have expected what you did to work, so it's odd.

Comment: @ADyson - Thanks very much for the input!  I really appreciate it!  I'll keep plugging away at the View, as well.

Comment: @ADyson - I can't figure out why this doesn't work, but your solution of the manually generated field results in the desired functionality, and that's the main point.  If you don't mind putting that last comment in an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct!  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little bit unhappy about making something into an answer when I can't give a proper explanation for why it's correct or necessary. Otherwise I'd have written it up as soon as I found it.

Comment: @ADyson - No worries, that's understandable.